# Looking for the Reactive way to implement a trigger for an expensive operation

Tags: system.reactive

My scenario is as follows:

1. Asynchronous events fire at arbitrary moments.
2. I would like to trigger an expensive operation for a batch of events, where batches of events are separated by 500 ms, for example. So, as long as events are spaced at less than 500ms - they belong to the same batch. But if 500 ms passed without any event, then it is time to trigger the expensive operation.
3. The expensive operation must have the data of the last event only, all the previous ones can be discarded. Ideally, I would like to avoid accumulating non constant number of events, because it is redundant.
4. The expensive operation is not triggered, if there is no window of quiet for the 500 ms. Even if it would take hours until such a window appears.

What I did so far is create a global instance of the `Subject<T>` class and every time there is an event, I am calling the `OnNext()` method to push the event to the observable stream designated by the subject.

Next, I understand I need to build a pipeline on top of my subject and that pipeline should produce the last element in each batch. And here is where I am blanking out.

Comment: What policy do you want to adopt if events are continually received at intervals less than 500ms?  I.e. if you received events every 100ms for 5 hours, would you want the expensive operation to a) be called at the end of 5 hours? b) at worst every 500ms c) some other?  Do you want to be able to cancel an ongoing operation if new data arrives during the calculation?

Comment: At the end of 5 hours. Let me add it to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly you can use the Throttle operator....

```
var subscription = myObservable
                   .Throttle(Timespan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                   .Subscribe(DoExpensiveOperation) ;
```

The [MSDN documentation](http://Ignores%20the%20values%20from%20an%20observable%20sequence%20which%20are%20followed%20by%20another%20value%20before%20due%20time%20with%20the%20specified%20source,%20dueTime%20and%20scheduler.) says **"Ignores the values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value before due time with the specified source, dueTime and scheduler."**  In other words, the throttle will only emit an event after waiting for the specified timespan.  However, every time a new event is received, the waiting period is reset so if you have events coming in quickly, nothing will be emitted until the end of the sequence.  [This website](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html) is an excellent background on Reactive operators.  I also recommend the [Rx .Net HOL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rxteam/2010/07/15/rx-hands-on-labs-published/) which is old and slightly outdated but which covers a lot of the concepts in a very readable way.

Comment: I will verify your answer and let you know.